# how to display remember me and forget password buttons on the same line.- flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display remember me button and the forget password text in a same line. how can I do this. image is showing my implementation so far. appreciate your help on this

[image]

```
CheckboxListTile(
                title: const Text(
                  "Remember Me",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: textGrey, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14),
                ),
                value: checkedValue,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                  setState(() {
                    if (isLoading != true) {
                      checkedValue = newValue!;
                      print(newValue);
                    }
                  });
                },
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0),
                controlAffinity:
                    ListTileControlAffinity.leading, //  <-- leading Checkbox
              ),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "Forget Password",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: textGrey, fontFamily: "Dubai", fontSize: 14),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Get.to(ForgetPassword());
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's solve my problem.

1. Create a row
2. Wrap CheckboxListTile with sizedbox
3. Add width to the SizedBox
4. Add SizedBox into a this row

An example:

```
Row(
 children [
   SizedBox(
       width: ..
       height: ..
       child: CheckboxListTile(...)
   ),
   Text(...)
 ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
 children: [
   SizedBox(
           width: 20,
           height: 20 ,
           child:
           
           Checkbox(value: 
           true, onChanged: (valye){

           })
           
          //   CheckboxListTile(onChanged: (bool? value) {  }, 
          //  value: true,
           
             
          //  )
   ),
   const SizedBox(
           width: 15,
           ),
   const Text('Remeber me')
 ]
),
    
    
    TextButton(onPressed: (){

    }, child: const Text('Forgot Password'))
      ],
    );
```

[image]